# window hidden behind menu

Tags: macos, menu-bar

the top of my photoshop is hidden under my mac menu and I can't seem to get it back to normal

[image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

shift/click/drag from the left-hand edge, which you can see, & the entire window will resize from all sides.

You can then drag it back into view.